# Solr Indexing in Storm topology vs Hbase NG Indexer

Tags: indexing, solr, hbase, apache-storm

I am working on designing the Data Indexing feature into Solr. We are using Storm Topology and have a Hbase Bolt where it is adding data into Hbase. The requirement is what ever data we are adding into Hbase, needs to be indexed as well.

The following are the options:

1. Add code to index in Solr, in Hbase bolt itself.
2. Create a new bolt, and separate Solr indexing
3. Use Hbase ND indexer, and integrate Solr indexer with Hbase row insertion.

The first two option, are similar to transactions, meaning both Hbase and Solr or none. But not sure, if we can do this, as we are dealing with data on large scale.

For third option, the starting point is Hbase, so all data is assumed to be in there. However, we do not have complete control on debugging because we have to deploy the jar into Indexer environment.

Please help me, which design is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis, we went ahead and implemented the design with NGHbas indexer. One argument is that we cannot gaurantee same data in hbase and solr as we cannot handle transactions at large scale. Also we have similar design for streaming data. So made used of the setup